# Does Kotlin's MutableList add() function always add to the end of the list?

Tags: kotlin

I am adding an element into a MutableList and I want to know its index.

```
mutableList.add(foo)
```

Will the index of the most recently added element always be the last index `mutableList.size - 1` like it is with `ArrayList`?

I don't want to use `mutableList.indexOf(foo)` because I believe it takes O(n). I'm not finding lot of documentation on these.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, `MutableList.add()` always adds to the end of the list (this is a requirement for any class implementing the interface). I've filed [an issue](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-25632) to say this explicitly in the documentation.

Answer (score 3):

`MutableList` is merely an interface. How are you initializing the list?

Using Kotlin methods like `mutableListOf()` creates `ArrayList` objects by default.

Comment: Yes it's using mutableListOf(). But I'm guessing it's not guaranteed to always use ArrayList right? Google might change it perhaps?

Comment: Kotlin is managed by JetBrains not Google, and I don't think they will change internal implementation on a whim. If you are afraid you can explicitly create your desired type of list instead of relying on the method.

Answer (score 1):

You raise a question that has never occurred to me since from testing and experience I've found that all new elements added with the `add` method are placed at the end. 
I believe that this is the case and won't change.  
Although not mentioned in the documentation, this case holds. If it didn't then for sure it would be in the documentation. Just like Set where it says

> A generic **unordered** collection

Answer (score 1):

On JVM, `MutableList` is equivalent to `java.util.List` whose `add` documentation does specify

> [Appends the specified element to the end of this list](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html#add-E-)